# Construction of a smooth manifolds ($M,g$) from a given symmetry group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, group-actions, geometric-topology

If a manifold $M^n$ is given then we know how to find a symmetry group(Automorphism group) of $M^n$ which will preserve some objects(like metric, connections etc) related to $M^n$.

But my query here is the converse of this that if some lie group $G$ is given, then how can we construct the possible manfolds $M^n$ whose automorphism group will be the given group $G$.

Suppose we are given a $n$-dimensional *lie group* $G$ which is inducing a set of diffeomorphisms
on some open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
$$x \longrightarrow x' = \underbrace{g\big(\{\theta^\nu \}_{\nu=1}^{n}\big)}_{\in
\hspace{1mm} G} \quad x$$ where $\theta^\nu $ are the group parameters of $G$;
$\quad x= (x^1,x^2,...,x^n)$,  $x'= ({x'}^1,{x'}^2,...,{x'}^n)$

and $x,x' \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now there will *always exist* **atleast a metric spaced manifold($M^n$)** such that *the automorphism group of $M^n$ is the given group $G$*, *subject to some invariance conditions* like
the diffeomorphisms of $M$ induced by $G$ will *preserve* the metric, affine connection etc.

> For example,
>
> Galilean group $G(d,1)$ acting as a diffeomorphism on
> $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ as,
>
> \begin{align}
>   x^i & \longrightarrow {x'}^i = 
>   {R}^{i}_{\hspace{1mm} j}x^j + b^i x^1 + > c^i;
>   \quad \quad \forall i=1,2,3,...,d
>   \\
>   x^0 & \longrightarrow x^0 + e
>   \end{align}
> where $R \in $ SO($d$), $\vec{b}$ & $\vec{c} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $e \in 
> \mathbb{R}$
>
> Then, a smooth ***Non-Riemannian
> manifold($N^{d+1},\gamma,\theta,\nabla$)*** *where $\gamma$ is a
> contravariant, twice-symmetric,positive tensor field and **degenerate
> metric**; $\theta$ is a 1-form which generates the kernel of $\gamma$;
> $\nabla$ is a symmetric affine connection that parallel transports both
> $\gamma$ & $\theta$*.
>
> $N^{d+1}$ is constructed as:
> \begin{align}
>   N^{d+1} & = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}
>   \\
>   \gamma & = \delta^{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \otimes 
>   \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j};
>   \quad \quad 
>   \forall i,j = 1,2,3,...,d
>   \\
>   \theta & = dt
>   \\
>   \Gamma^{\rho}_{\hspace{1mm}\mu\nu} & = 0;
>   \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
>   \forall \mu,\nu,\rho = 0,1,2,3,...,d
>   \end{align}
> Now, the *automorphisms of ($N^{d+1},\gamma,\theta,\nabla$)* i.e. the
> transformations which
> *preserve all the geometric ingredients $\gamma,\theta,\nabla$* constitute
> the *Galilean Group$(G(d,1))$*.
>
> Now, from knowing the $G(d,1)$ and its diffeomorphic action on open sets
> of $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$, how to arrive at the manifold
> structure($N^{d+1},\gamma,\theta,\nabla$)?
>
> Many such constructions of manifolds from a given symmetry group can be found in
> *Duval, C.; Gibbons, G. W.; Horvathy, P. A.; Zhang, P. M.*, [**Carroll versus Newton and Galilei: two dual non-Einsteinian concepts of time**](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/31/8/085016), Classical Quantum Gravity 31, No. 8, Article ID 085016, 24 p. (2014). [ZBL1295.83006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1295.83006).

Reframing my question,

Question: What are the methods to construct such manifolds $M^n$ mentioned above, if I know the action of $G$ as diffeomorphisms on some open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

(P.S. I will be glad to hear from the respected community and also it will be helpful if you kindly mention how the construcion of the manifolds $M^n$ will change if the '*subject to some invariance conditions*' mentioned above are also altered.)

Comment: Google finds this when you poke it: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87070/can-every-lie-group-be-realized-as-the-full-isometry-group-of-a-riemannian-manif

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for sharing the above link but it only states that that every lie group can be realized as an automorphism group of some Riemannian manifold.

But my question is what are the algorithms involved in constructing such manifolds

Comment: I have update my query to new formatting and inserted some references that will be helpful for the scientific community to solve the problem.

Comment: It is not even clear what an algorithm means in this setting.

Comment: @MoisheKohan By algorithm I mean to ask what are some methods that can be performed to construct manfolds from a given group action so that the group arises as the set automorphisms of the manifold that preserves the geometric structure of the manifolds.

Comment: Then do not call it an algorithm and revise your question accordingly. More importantly, check the linked MO question and papers mentioned there. Lively, these will answer your question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ok I have changed the word to 'method' but I have checked bit they are not describing the methods actually  they are only saying that this can be performed.

Comment: Is this what you might have in mind? Perhaps the most commonly used method is the method of homogeneous spaces. Start with a Lie group $G$ a left-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$, and a closed subgroup $H < G$. Form the right coset space $G / H$ with its induced Riemannian metric. The group $G$ acts on the left of $G/H$ by isometries. In many cases that action is faithful, and in many of those cases the action by $G$ is most (if not all) of the full isometry group of $G/H$.

Comment: For example if $G=O(3;\mathbb R)$ and $H$ is an $O(2;\mathbb R)$ subgroup then $G/H$ is the $2$-sphere on which $G$ acts as the full isometry group.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks man for your proposed solution, but can you write the answer in more details that how can I construct the metric, the connections and all other geometric constituents of the manifold

Comment: Well, that's a whole course in homogeneous manifolds, so no, I can't do that in the scope of an MSE answer. I might suggest that you look into the topic some on your own; there's lots of good books.

Comment: @LeeMosher Can you mention me the accurate sources or topics in which I will get my targeted answer in details

Comment: @LeeMosher Since the constructed manifolds are not unique so there will also exist other methods of constructions which you have not mentioned here

Comment: Your last comment is incorrect: the same Lie group $G$ can have many different closed subgroups, therefore $G$ can have many different manifolds on which it acts.  To start you off on sources, even the [brief wikipedia page on homogeneous spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space) is pretty good: it has lots of examples; and a few references, including the Kobayashi-Nomizu book which will have plenty about examples and connections, etc.

Comment: @LeeMosher Ok thanks